# Unable to select states object property with ngxs

Tags: typescript, ngxs

I simplified at problem i'm having.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-repro-eymfpn

I am making a select on a objects property in a ngxs state. The first time it works, but clicking on the button it does not give new data to the subscribe after it having updated the state. (Setting the selector to the data object, will make it work)

How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly subscribing to your observable. First, you need to set the returned observable to some property on your component class and then subscribe to it in ngOnIt.  Another option is to use the async pipe in your template, which will hookup the binding for you.

example 1:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-repro-hmulls?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

example 2:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-repro-wl9thh?file=src/app/app.component.ts